# User input in game loop

Tags: javascript, game-loop, events

I am building a simple multi-player fly-around-a-3D-world game in Javascript/webGL/websocket (Chrome, Firefox mostly).

How should I handle and process user input?

My preliminary design (untested) is to first just track which keys are down in the event handler:

```
var keys = [];

document.onkeydown = document.onkeyup = function(evt) {
   keys[evt.charCode] = evt.type == "keydown";
   keys[CTRL] = evt.ctrlKey;
   keys[SHIFT] = evt.shiftKey;
   websock.send(JSON({time: (new Date()).gettime(),
      down: evt.type == "keydown",
      key: evt.charCode,
      shift: evt.shiftKey, ctrl: evt.ctrlKey }));
};
```

and then, in my [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) callback, compute how many time-slices (say 20 per second?) have elapsed since the last render callback, and then compute that many time-steps using the booleans in the `keys` array to determine if to apply a left bank, right bank, up down and accelerate and so that time-step for each player.

How effective / responsive is this?  Is there a better way?  And is there a neater way to deal with latency than just backdating changes for other user's ships?

Comment: @Bane I don't think you even answered the actual question.  Then again, most of my questions here don't get answers I'm happy with :(

Comment: Would you be satisfied with "Depends"? I just gave you an idea of what I think would be more effective and logical... I can't vouche for myself, but the rest of the site is pretty darn effective in answering questions, and if the questions don't get answered, maybe it's the asker's problem.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** there's a bug in your code.

At the new Date().getTime() part (you can write it like that, no need for extra parenthesis).

1. Not all your clients are going to have the same time.
2. One could easily change the date values being sent to your server.

So, that value isn't very reliable (in case you plan to use it for something important), you better calculate it on the server side.

Never, ever trust the client with anything other than their current state of input.

I strongly suggest that your movement has nothing to do with rendering.

I usually have one function called `logic`, and that function basically calls all the objects' `update` methods, and gives them the time passed. The player class, then, has an input listener, and in its function it checks which keys pressed, and depending on the time, reacts accordingly.

```
if (player.input.right)
{
    velocity.x = const;
}

//Do some physics.

position.x += velocity.x * dt
```

I call this logic function ~30 times per second, so it's responsive enough. As for the netcode, it's best to record input and only send that to the server. The server only sends back the difference in the game state since the last message (see: [Backbone.js](http://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CF8QFjAA&url=http://backbonejs.org/&ei=kgAqUPqvD9HAtAbH54GYDw&usg=AFQjCNEQiFXPSOG9TaqO8NIjr09_aBVI1w&sig2=eT0cnyT8nSFR8XmKGHPXcA) diff).

Comment: I agree with your sentiment, it was misleading to call my game loop callback 'render' and I've changed that.  Regards your use of delta time, http://gafferongames.com/game-physics/fix-your-timestep/ is always a good link for anyone googling this later.

Comment: As a side note.. if timestamp is not coming from the client, then the server would favor players with better connections automatically, so overall I think that it would need some sort of time sync to determine average connection speeds for different clients so that i.e. modem and dsl -connections could compete against each other and game would implement requirement of "fairness" better.